# How to count the tag values with specific key in influxDB?

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I am using the command "show tag values on  with key = " it is showing me the list of tags but I want to count the entries related to that tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to know tag values cardinality:

```
SHOW TAG VALUES EXACT CARDINALITY WITH KEY = "myTagKey"
```

Doc: https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/spec/#show-tag-values-cardinality